# behavior of the solution of a polynomial equation

Tags: numerical-methods

Given a positive integer $m\ge 3$, consider the function $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(1-x)^{m-2}-\frac{3x}{2-x}
\end{equation*}
It is easy to see that $f(x)=0$ has unique solution in $[0,1]$, $\phi_m$.

What is the order of $\phi_m$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Whyt do you mean by "order"? It's always a zero of $f_m$ of order one.

Comment: Thank you both for your contributions. I was not aware of Lambert's $W_0$ function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $a>0$ you get $(1-x)^{m-2}\approx 0$ on $x\in[a,1]$ for $m$ large enough. The value of the second term will be decidedly positive on $[a,1]$, so that there can be no root there. The root will have to be close to zero.

Introduce exponentials for the non-zero terms $1-x$ and $2-x$ to get
$$
e^{(m-2)\ln(1-x)}e^{\ln(1-x/2)}=\frac32x
$$
In a first approximation, assuming that $mx^2$ is small, this gives
$$
(m-2.5)x\cdot e^{(m-2.5)x}=\frac23(m-2.5)\implies x=\frac{W_0(\frac23(m-2.5))}{(m-2.5)}$$ for the approximate value, and then also
$$
x=\frac23e^{-(m-2.5)x}=\frac23e^{W_0(\frac23(m-2.5))}
$$
Asymptotically this means $x_m=O(m^{-1}\log(m))$

Comment: This is a real good approximation of the solution. For $m=10^4$ it gives $x=0.000687823$ while the exact solution is $0.000687557$

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for comments.*

LutzL provided an elegant answer to the question and a very good estimate of the solution for large values of $m$.

If we use
$$x_0=\frac{W_0(\frac23(m-2.5))}{(m-2.5)}$$ as the starting value of Newton method, the second iterate will be given by
$$x_1=\frac{(x_0-2) (1-x_0)^{m-2}+3 x_0}{(1-x_0)^{m-3} (x_0 (m-1)-2 m+3)-3}+x_0$$

Just a few numbers (I cannot resist when I see equations !)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
m & x_0 & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 3 & 0.515255 & 0.349032 &  0.354249 \\
 4 & 0.378096 & 0.284280 &  0.288654 \\
 5 & 0.308381 & 0.244906 &  0.248165 \\
 6 & 0.264321 & 0.217346 &  0.219832 \\
 7 & 0.233313 & 0.196597 &  0.198553 \\
 8 & 0.210018 & 0.180237 &  0.181814 \\
 9  & 0.191726 & 0.166909 &  0.168210 \\
 10 & 0.176897 & 0.155786 &  0.156877 \\
 20 & 0.105401 & 0.098020 &  0.098344 \\
 30 & 0.078014 & 0.074025 &  0.074178 \\
 40 & 0.062937 & 0.060368 &  0.060456 \\
 50 & 0.053219 & 0.051396 &  0.051453 \\
 60 & 0.046362 & 0.044988 &  0.045028 \\
 70 & 0.041231 & 0.040151 &  0.040180 \\
 80 & 0.037229  & 0.036352 &  0.036374 \\
 90  & 0.034008 & 0.033280 &  0.033297 \\
 100 & 0.031354 & 0.030737 &  0.030751 \\
 200 & 0.018225 & 0.018022 &  0.018025 \\
 300 & 0.013187 & 0.013082 &  0.013083 \\
 400 & 0.010454 & 0.010388 &  0.010389 \\
 500 & 0.008718 & 0.008672 &  0.008673 \\
 600 & 0.007508 & 0.007475 &  0.007475 \\
 700 & 0.006614 & 0.006588  &  0.006588 \\
 800 & 0.005923  & 0.005902 &  0.005902 \\
 900  & 0.005372 & 0.005355 &  0.005355 \\
 1000 & 0.004921 & 0.004907 &  0.004907
\end{array}
\right)$$